# Bypass AC compressor on 2008 Chrysler Town and County 3.8L

Tags: ac, chrysler, compressor, serpentine-belt, town-and-country

Is it possible to use a shorter belt to bypass the a/c compressor? If so what length and or part number for belt would I need? Vehicle is a 2008 Chrysler Town and Country with the 3.8L engine and has rear and front HVAC with dual climate on the driver and passenger front.

Comment: Why not just pull the compressor clutch relay?